# How to efficiently updating list of dict key-values with list of value in Python

Tags: python, list, performance

The objective is to update new key-value in a list of dict, whereby the value is from another nested list.

This can be realised via

```
ls1=[[1,23],[2,34,5]]
ls2=[dict(t=1),dict(t=1)]
all_data=[]

for x,y in zip(ls1,ls2):
    y['new']=x
    all_data.append(y)
```

For compactness, I would like to have the for-loop in the form of `list comprehension`.

```
all_data=[y.update({'new':x}) for x,y in zip(ls1,ls2)]
```

But, by doing so, I got a list of `None` instead. May I know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `.update()` returns `None`, not the updated dictionary. You can *bitwise-OR* two dictionaries together (Python >= 3.9) to obtain what you want:

```py
all_data = [y | {'new':x} for x,y in zip(ls1,ls2)]
```

If you need to support Python < 3.9, you can construct a new dictionary from the `.items()` of the old one instead:

```py
all_data = [dict(y.items(), new=x) for x,y in zip(ls1,ls2)]
```

Note that both the above solutions leave the original dictionaries unchanged.

Comment: You can also use `{**y, 'new': x}` which will work for non-string keys as well.